# How to plot a graph in excel work sheet using c++ in windows mobile platform?

Tags: c++, windows, excel, graph, windows-mobile

How can i plot a graph for the particular data in the same excel sheet using c++ in windows mobile platform?

***For example:***

I have an excel sheet say **ItemDetails.xls** with an header as "**Date**" & "**Item Count**" as mentioned below:-

```
Date          Item Count
02-06-13         20
03-06-13         15
04-06-13         10
05-06-13         5
```

*How can I plot a graph for the above data in the same excel sheet i.e. **ItemDetails.xls**?*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can not automate excel on windows mobile cause it does not expose an excel obejct as on desktop PC. There are alternative third party tools.

Why use excel? Such imple graph can be created with simple drawing commands or in javascript on a web page.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe save your excel file into csv format first so that your c++ will be able to read it easily.